# Difference between NAN & INF in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, terminology

In MATLAB, INF means infinity and NAN means Not a Number

Apparently both these seem similar but there must be some difference ,because of which MATLAB makes represents them separatley?
Why in some operations output is Inf while in others , output is NAN?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd like to point out that it is not just MATLAB that makes this distinction. INF and NAN are both defined in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically they are two different concepts.  While in real analysis, infinity is not a real number it does represent an unbounded limit and is part of the set that makes up extended real numbers.  That makes infinity a symbol that can result from a mathematical operation, i.e. it is a valid answer.

A NaN, on the other hand, represents a result that is not numerical.

I like to initialize floating point arrays when allocated to NaN because it will make certain bugs (e.g. off by one errors) obvious.

Comment: “a result that is not numerical” could also be described as “an error condition”. When an operation cannot be performed, one can return NaN instead of throwing an error. This is useful because for example people don’t expect `/` to throw an error. Apparently MATLAB returns complex results for `acos(2)`, but in C++ that would return NaN as well, rather than throw an exception.

Comment: That is a great point. In high performance computing (particularly back in the early days), exception handling or throwing an interrupt is an expensive operation. Having a NaN that propagates through a calculation allows error checking to be applied more strategically in the code.